# How to add custom created column in github project boards's progress bar?

Tags: github, github-projects

I created a project board in GitHub using default Kanaban. I've added my own column, but it isn't reflected in the project progress bar. Only To-Do, In-Progress & Done are reflected and it is bugging me out. Is there a way to reflect the new columns in the project bar too? Thanks.

( For context purpose: The progress bar is the one with project's name and shows the columns relative status with respect to the number of cards in the columns. White -> Todo, Purple -> In Progress, Green -> Done. )

https://help.github.com/articles/about-project-boards

I tried fiddling around automation properties of the columns (I didn't work as I expected). In project properties, I've unchecked & again checked the show progress bar column. But it is still showing the original three columns and not the new ones.

expected:
progress-bar -> x-done / y-in progress / z - custom / ... / a-to-do

actual:
progress-bar -> x-done / y-in progress / z-to do

Answer (score 0):

According to my fiddling with the GitHub project board, the progress bar shows the (sum of the) amount of items in columns marked with an automation preset (To do, In progress, Done).

Columns with automation preset "None" are not shown in the progress bar.

I don't think you are able to add more presets to create your expected progress bar `x-done / y-in progress/ z-custom / ... / a-to-do`. At least not yet, although I checked 2 years after the question was posted.

You can, however, definitely do something like `x-done / y-in progress + z-custom / a-to-do` by setting the custom column's automation preset to "In progress".

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @hilipati's answer: no, GitHub only takes into account "To do", "In progress", and "Done" columns. *However*, if you set the column's automation to one of the above presets, it will count. So, for example, you can split the "In progress" column into two columns -- one for new PRs and another for reviewed PRs, and both will count towards the "In progress" (purple) section of the progress bar.